# How to expand variable into nested directory in maven-archetype

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-archetype

Suppose I have set `groupId` to `com.example`, and `artifactId` to `fancy.project`, and now I want to create a archetype, such that when created, expands into the following structure:

```
|--src
  |--main
    |--com
      |--example
        |-fancy
          |-project
            |-App.java
```

That is, I wonder how to expand a variable into a nested directory.

I understand that the dual-underscore-wrapped variables will be substituted in file/directory names, but I can only get the following with `__groupId__`.

```
|--src
  |--main
    |--com.example
      |-fancy.project
        |-App.java
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As input to the archetype you can specify the `package` option (which would then follow your input, the groupId and artifactId concatenation if you want, even though it is not always the case and hence provide even more flexibility).

Then, in your archetype you can use the `packageInPathFormat` option (available since archetype **2.2**) which would replace any dot `.` into slash `\` and as such transforming it to a path into the generated project.

However, the option is not officially documented (pity) even though supported and works fine for such a scenario.

[Looking at the code](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/20214237/), the `DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator` and its `getPackageInPathFormat` provide the concerned transformation from the `package` option to a path, while the [org.apache.maven.archetype.common.Constants.PACKAGE_IN_PATH_FORMAT](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-common/apidocs/org/apache/maven/archetype/common/Constants.html#PACKAGE_IN_PATH_FORMAT) is the official entry point for this option.

Some externals pointers on the usage of this option:

- http://geekofficedog.blogspot.be/2013/08/creating-maven-archetypes-tutorial.html
- http://www.theotherian.com/2012/05/maven-archetypes-part-2-how-do-i-create.html

---

To further explain:

- You can have the `__packageInPathFormat__` folder under your src/main/java, for example
- The `__packageInPathFormat` would then be replaced by the `package` option transforming dots into slashes
- The `package` option has a default value to `groupId`, so if you don't specify it, for a `groupId` with value `com.sample`, the path would be `com/sample`
- You can hence specify at invocation time the package desired via `-Dpackage=your.package` repeating the values for `-DgroupId` and `-DartifactId` (a bit verbose and error prone though), the final result will actually be what you expected (transformed to correct path).
- You can specify new default values via a `archetype-metada.xml` file, as specified in the [official documentation](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-metadata.html), via the `requiredProperties` section, you could have something like:

  ```
  <requiredProperties>
      <requiredProperty key="package">
          <defaultValue>__groupId__.__artifactId__</defaultValue>
      </requiredProperty>
  </requiredProperties>
  ```

  However, the generated path would then be `com.sample/artifactid` rather than `com/sample/artifactid`. Hence it would not work as expected due to the processing workflow which would replace the placeholders after transforming it to a path (pity!).
  (Note: it would transform the dot we provided as configured value, but would then not transform dots into the replaced placeholders).

  As of a quick code analysis, seems like the `DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator` class in its `generateArchetype` method is preparing the context too early (in its `prepareVelocityContext` method, where the `packageInPathFormat` is transformed and added to the context), then the context is passed to `processArchetypeTemplate*` methods which would eventually invoke the Velocity engine (which is going to replace placeholders then). I am not a Velocity expert though, hence I may miss some glue, but the observed behavior and the code workflow seem to lead to this conclusion.

Comment: @Matteo Actually I have come to this `packageInPathFormat` option before, but in my case, this provides only a formatted path for the `groupId`. The `artifactId` is not included, so I still have to expand that myself. Any idea how to do this generically?

Comment: Ah, I got your point. I should set the package option as the concatenation of `groupId` and `artifactId`. However, I have to explicitly specify `-Dpackage=blahblah`. Is it possible to automate this concatenation?

Comment: @Davyzhu I updated my answer but no good news, you can re-define default values and even with placeholders, but then the path would not be what we expected

Comment: @Matteo Thanks for your time and effort! I have tried setting `defaultValue` with curly brace placeholders like `${groupId}.${artifactId}` but only get rubbish. They are treated literally. Can you point me to the right direction why this placeholder fails? To make it more general, who (or which part of code) is responsible to substitute curly brace placeholders and when it happens? Anyway, your answer suffice for my original post already. Accepting.

Comment: @Davyzhu I've added some further details concerning the code at the bottom of my answer, hope it can be of further help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the variables `__groupId__` and `__artifactId__` you can use `${groupId}` and `${artifactId}` respectively instead (I don't know if these were around when this question was posted), so it would look something like this:

```
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="package">
        <defaultValue>${groupId}.${artifactId}</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
</requiredProperties>
```

When generating a project using these, in interactive mode it will actually request to enter the package, and in batch mode it will automatically generate CLOSE to what OP wanted.

Ex. `groupId` being `me.zenisbestwolf` and `artifactId` being `fancy-app` will generate the path of `me/zenisbestwolf/fancy-app`. Unfortunately automating the artifact ID to go from `fancy.app` to `fancy/app` like OP wanted to isn't possible without manually defining the package, AFAIK.